# Getting values from selected option in select menu and repeat them in similar selected menus Java Script, PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following select menu that will be repeated 8 times by php for loop. I want, using js, to set onchange event to repeat the selected option from the first menu in the rest of the 7 menus, and off course repeat the value of the option as well.  Given that I read the select menu values for mysql table:

```
for ($a=1; $a<=$n; $a++) 
{ 
readtable_no_order ("rooms"); //php function to read table
echo '<select name="hOffers['.$a.']'.'" class= "select">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{echo '<option value ="'. $row['room'] . '">'. 
  $row['room'] . '</option>';}
  echo '</select><br>';

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

change your html to

```
<select name="rooms" class="rooms"> 
<option value="single">Single</option> 
<option value="double">Double</option> 
<option value="triple">Triple</option> 
</select>
```

and add a js:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('rooms');
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onchange = function() {
        for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].value = this.value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the it doesn't work properly as I use while loop to set the select options. so all options are changing to single, double. I would like every individual option change respectively. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

U need to use unique IDs in HTML :

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0;$i < 8;$i++) {
      echo '<select named="rooms" id="rooms'.$i.'" class="cbo_room">'
    }
```

Use a class to group the comboboxes together :

```
$(function() {
        $('.cbo_room').change(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
       });
});
```

Comment: Seems i forgot some () updated the code. Please not this is just a small example and not the full working code